# How do I prevent my dropdown from closing when clicking inside it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to create a dropdown for [my website](http://servers.binf.ku.dk/hemaexplorerbeta/), but I am having some problems with it.

On my website, if clicked on "Select Populations" the popup will appear (FYI: clicking "submit" will have things appear in it). And when I click inside of it, it always closes down. How can I prevent it from doing so? I only want it to close if clicked outside of the field.

Here's the code I use:

CSS:

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

.dropdown-menu:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: '';
}

.dropdown-menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button data-toggle="dropdown" id="submitButton" type="button" id="pops" >Select Populations</button>
    <ul id="popupDropDown" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The bubble still closes when I click inside of it.

Comment: 2 things:1. you have 6 buttons using the same ID:submitButton, please bear in mind that ID has to be unique;2. when you click on <Population> your div "dropdown" is given a class "open" which will make your dropdown menu display, so if you want it stay you have to change your event listener to handle this properly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`'.dropdown-menu'` catches the the bubble. There is no need to catch elements inside of the dropdown in this case.

`e.stopPropagation()` prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 12):

Bootstrap 5 has now an [autoclose feature](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/#auto-close-behavior) where you can configure this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Use `data-bs-toggle` parameter in the `button` html tag.

Example:

`<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false"> Clickable inside</button>`

the value of data-b-toggle can be `data-bs-auto-close="true" or "false"` or `data-bs-auto-close="outside" or "inside"`

i have tried this in my code. Its working fine.

Comment: Note that the auto-close data attribute was introduced in Bootstrap 5.