# Disable the user being able to click on a li element

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and am trying to disable an li so when the user clicks on one of the li elements in the dropdown nothing happens. Currently when I click on the top li element the dropdown closes.  I want it to stay open.
Most of the resources I have found have been about disabling links.  I want to create a drop down similar to the one on Facebook.

Here is my html

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li id="test"><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

here is my css

```
#test{
  background-color:red;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

and here is a link to jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/aaronmk2/DTcHh/67643/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid dropdown menu close on click inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089297/avoid-dropdown-menu-close-on-click-inside)

Comment: What do you want to do when a user clicks on any one the `<li>`?

Comment: @Abrar, currently when I click on the <li> the dropdown closes.  I want the drop down to stay open.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent my dropdown from closing when clicking inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031635/how-do-i-prevent-my-dropdown-from-closing-when-clicking-inside-it)

Comment: $('li').on('click', function(event){
    // The event won't be propagated up to the document NODE and 
    // therefore delegated events won't be fired
    event.stopPropagation();
});

Comment: Are you trying to target just the disabled menu item at the top, or all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the single requirement of keeping the dropdown open when you click an `li`, the code below will work. Simply [stop the event propagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/):

```
$(".dropdown-menu li").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4vve8yL/).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `data-toggle` property from your button and use the following JS to solve your problem:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function (event) {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
});

$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    if (!$('.dropdown-toggle').is(e.target) 
        && $('.dropdown-toggle').has(e.target).length === 0 
        && $('.open').has(e.target).length === 0
    ) {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').removeClass('open');
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/67653/